# pre gives me empty lines before and after

Tags: css

I had a box with 3 divs which were all a line each. I gave them each a background color. I wanted to give one of the `<pre>` so it would hold spaces and newlines like a user may wish. However now that i do that i see an empty line before and after the pre. I have a border solid black 1px in the parent div so i can easily see the background color of the div before it and the border of the parent div.

How do i remove the empty line before and after the pre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This table](http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm) shows that most browsers add default margins around PRE. You need to remove them if you don't want extra space.

Comment: Thats a good reference but i am asking how do i remove it? it shows `block` under pre so i tried display: inline and it didnt help. How do i remove it?

Comment: You're looking at the wrong row. Look at `margin`. (Note that I wrote margin, not display.)

Comment: margin was the FIRST thing i tried. However i must have done .pre or something. Because... i wrote the same css and it appears to work now.